# Open eclipse projects synced with git that are outside the workspace

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a project outside of my eclipse workspace, and I am using git to update it, and I want to use eclipse to work on the files. But if I do import existing projects into workspace in eclipse, will it only copy the contents of the project at the time? So when I pull new changes into the project, will the files automatically update in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, they will automatically update. However, you may need to refresh the project (use `F5`) in order to load changes in currently open files.

Comment: @Vulcan Ok, so do I first create a new project and then import the outside folder, or do I just press import and select the folder?

Comment: I would choose "New Project" and then in the project wizard, choose your git-updated project's root as the Eclipse project location. Eclipse should import everything automatically once you do so.

Comment: @Vulcan Thank you. But I just picked "Import" and then selected the folder and I left it outside instead of copying the files into the workspace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicked `Import` -> `Existing projects into workspace` and then selected the folder that was outside and left `copy projects into workspace` unchecked. It now works.

Answer (score 2):

*But if I do import existing projects into workspace in eclipse, will it only copy the contents of the project at the time?*

**The project in eclipse is not just a copy of the project.Strictly speaking eclipse will make links to the project dir.**

*So when I pull new changes into the project, will the files automatically update in eclipse?*

**If the project changed outside eclipse,  they will automatically update.But you need to refres h the project in eclipse. Before you refresh the project ,eclipse will prompt message.**

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the Eclipse git integration plugin "egit" to do all your git management from inside Eclipse. It can handle projects outside the workspace perfectly fine.

One benefit of that is that you avoid the need to manually synchronize the contents of currently opened editors, because the changed file on disk is handled correctly inside Eclipse and the content of (non dirty) editors is automatically updated.